XPS 15 does not charge, unless battery below 10%
My laptop (a Dell XPS 15 9500) doesn’t charge the battery unless the charge drops below a certain threshold (I think around 10%). How can I fix this?
The issue occurs when, for example, the laptop battery is 100% charged. I’ll unplug it to go somewhere, and then when I plug it back in, it doesn’t charge anymore. The battery continues to drain until the laptop shuts off, or I reboot it when the battery drops below 10%.
This seems to be a recent issue, possibly due to the upgrade to Linux Mint 22 or maybe the BIOS update, but I’m not sure. Any help would be appreciated.
Some details of my system
dodohjk@dodohjk-XPS-15-9500:~$ inxi -Fxxrzc0
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
  Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: Muffin dm: LightDM
    Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma base: Ubuntu 24.04 noble
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 15 9500 v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Dell model: 0RHXRG v: A03 serial: <superuser required> part-nu: 097D
    UEFI: Dell v: 1.31.0 date: 07/08/2024
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 19.5 Wh (49.9%) condition: 39.1/84.3 Wh (46.3%)
    volts: 11.8 min: 11.4 model: BYD DELL M59JH07 serial: <filter>
    status: charging
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: Intel Core i7-10750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Comet Lake rev: 2 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 914 high: 2174 min/max: 800/5000 cores: 1: 800 2: 800
    3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 2174 7: 800 8: 800 9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800
    bogomips: 62399
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Dell driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-9.5 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,DP-2,DP-3
    bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:9bc4
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] vendor: Dell
    driver: N/A arch: Turing pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:1f95
  Device-3: Realtek Integrated_Webcam_HD driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-11:3 chip-ID: 0bda:5510
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915 display-ID: :0
    screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3072x1920 s-dpi: 120
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: Sharp 0x14d1 res: 3072x1920 dpi: 232
    diag: 396mm (15.6")
  API: EGL v: 1.5 platforms: device: 0 drv: iris device: 1 drv: swrast
    surfaceless: drv: iris x11: drv: iris inactive: gbm,wayland
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
    device-ID: 8086:9bc4
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:06c8
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-47-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi vendor: Rivet Networks Dual Band
    Wi-Fi 6 Killer AX1650s 160MHz 2x2 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:06f0
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-14:4 chip-ID: 8087:0026
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.2
    lmp-v: 11 sub-v: 20f9
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 325.52 GiB (34.1%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: 2300 NVMe 1024GB size: 953.87 GiB
    speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> temp: 32.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 85.95 GiB used: 16.98 GiB (19.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 55.9 MiB (58.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-3: /home size: 557.03 GiB used: 308.49 GiB (55.4%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p8
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 7.63 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p9
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C pch: 46.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 2111 pm: dpkg pkgs: 2096 pm: flatpak pkgs: 15
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/packages.linuxmint.com/packages wilma main upstream import backport
    2: deb http://mirrors.coreix.net/ubuntu noble main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http://mirrors.coreix.net/ubuntu noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http://mirrors.coreix.net/ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list
    1: deb-src https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/packages.linuxmint.com/packages wilma main upstream import backport
    2: deb-src http://mirrors.coreix.net/ubuntu noble main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb-src http://mirrors.coreix.net/ubuntu noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb-src http://mirrors.coreix.net/ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
Info:
  Memory: total: 16 GiB note: est. available: 15.37 GiB used: 5.71 GiB (37.2%)
  Processes: 394 Power: uptime: 50m wakeups: 0 Init: systemd v: 255
    target: graphical (5) default: graphical
  Compilers: gcc: 13.2.0 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.21 running-in: gnome-terminal
    inxi: 3.3.34


my BIOS information
[sudo] password for dodohjk:          
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Dell Inc.
    Version: 1.31.0
    Release Date: 07/08/2024
    ROM Size: 32 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Smart battery is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Function key-initiated network boot is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 1.31

BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Abbreviated
    Installable Languages: 1
        enUS
    Currently Installed Language: enUS


Some pics from the UEFI/BIOS




Enter your UEFI(BIOS) and there it is all set up (or should be). Supposing your battery is not dead yet.

what is the command to find the UEFI(BIOS) info? sudo dmidecode | grep -i BIOS is enough?

I think I understand what you mean now @VlastimilBurián. I have entered the BIOS and all seems fine, the battery is not new but still hold some charge.  I have added some pictures. What should I look for exactly?

This question belongs on Superuser as it is a question of hardware and the BIOS and not Unix or Linux or even an OS issue.

This question belongs on Superuser as it is about system hardware and the BIOS and not Unix or Linux.

i see, is there a way to move this question to superuser? or should i start a new one?

Unfortunately, automatic migration only exists from here to StackOverflow; you will need to create the question on SU yourself. Please delete this one to avoid cross-posting, which is discouraged and will lead to closing this question (and the one on SU).
